# Creating a usb stick for installing Windows

Tags: boot, usb

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04, and I'm trying to create a USB stick for installing Windows. I have the Windows image I need to put on the stick -- no problem there. But I've been thwarted at every turn.

My first thought was to use Startup Disk Creator, but that only works for Linux images. Next I tried **Woeusb**, but it's no longer maintained and I couldn't get it to run. So I turned to **Unetbootin**, but I couldn't get it to accept my USB drive. I tried it with a single FAT partition on the USB drive (what could be more vanilla?), both empty and nonempty.  I also tried using **gparted** to fix the USB drive, but it wouldn't recognize the USB drive either. So I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I use [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) so I can boot any of my Ubuntu and Windows installers from a single USB.

Comment: **Officially** only the "Media Creation Tool" from Microsoft is able to create bootable Windows installation media.  Unfortunately it only works for Windows. It's not to say there may be other methods that work but MS tends to make things difficult

Comment: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works with all current versions and flavours of Ubuntu and can create USB boot drives from various Linux iso files as well as Windows installers for all current versions of Windows (8, 10, 11) that can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias legacy mode).

Answer (score 2):

`mkusb` works with all current versions and flavours of Ubuntu and can create USB boot drives from various Linux iso files as well as Windows installers for all current versions of Windows (8, 10, 11) that can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias legacy mode).